# svn update --ignore-externals w/subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Is there a way set Subversive to use --ignore-externals on future updates for a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. A search on the bug tracker shows that it's been [considered but not taken up](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=2371198). You could alias 'svn up' to 'svn up --ignore-externals' in your shell, but that'll affect all projects.